# Mongoose Not Saving Nested Arrays / Deep Objects Using .save() function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB, and I'm using the Mongoose API.

I have a method which I'm hoping will allow me to find a "habit" within my user object. A habit is an object that lives in array of habits. I am passing the method a UUID to find the habit.

Here is my method:

```
async updateHabit(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.headers
    const { habitId  } = req.params
    const habit = req.body
    
    const user = await User.findById(user_id)
  
    const habitIndex = user.habits.findIndex(habit => habit.id == habitId)

    user.habits[habitIndex] = habit

    console.log(user.habits)

    await user.save()

    return res.json(user.habits)
  }
```

What's strange is the console log right above the save method, which shows the most current version of my user, is showing correctly. It logs the user's habits with the updated habit taking place of the old one - at the index in which the old one lived.

However the save method is not writing this to my database. I have almost an identical delete method which is working just fine.

I have tried changing from a PUT to a POST (thinking, 'well, I'm actually posting a new array') - but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to explicitly specify the change or which property you have changed. It's kinda surprising how mongoose treats when saving with nested or deep object properties.  Here is the documentation on mongoose website: [check here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

In your case you may need to do an extra step, which is to specify the property/path being modified like:

```
user.markModified('habits')
await user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the case of mongoose/mongodb strangely not storing this object

```
{
   name: { ar: 'بيلاروس', en: 'Belarus' },
   _id: new ObjectId("62af094497597de6050e3af2"),
   alpha2: 'by',
   phoneCode: '+375'
}
```

So I tried to convert it using JSON parse/stringify to be like this:

```
{
  name: { ar: 'بيلاروس', en: 'Belarus' },
  _id: '62af094497597de6050e3af2',
  alpha2: 'by',
  phoneCode: '+375'
}
```

using JSON functions

```
let parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```